# USB Debugging/Identifying

Tags: macos, usb, hardware

I have a pair of headphones with an ARM chipset of some sort, and wondered if there was a way of identifying it with a micro USB plugged in, but then I thought, how would I identify a USB device in the generic case?

**Given USB port X, and device Y, how might I go about finding information in OS X about what device Y might be?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is the kind of information you are looking for but there is the System Information application.

You can launch it from Spotlight, or by clicking on the Apple symbol in the menubar and selecting "About the Mac" and then clicking "System Report...".

If you select USB from the list of hardware types on the left-hand side, you will get some information about the USB devices plugged into your Mac including VendorID, ProductID and Manufacturer.

[image: Screenshot of System Information application]